# if loop win while not working in shell script

Tags: unix, if-statement

I have a simple `if else` loop inside `while` but it's not giving me the proper output needed.

```
#!/bin/bash

set -x
inputFile=/data2/example/output1.txt
while read col1 col2 col3; do
if [ $col2=='Success' ]
then
echo " This is Green"
else
echo " This is Red"
fi
done < ${inputFile}
```

Output I'm getting is:

```
+ read col1 col2 col3
+ '[' Success==Success ']'
+ echo ' This is Green'
 This is Green
+ read col1 col2 col3
+ '[' Success==Success ']'
+ echo ' This is Green'
 This is Green
+ read col1 col2 col3
+ '[' Failed==Success ']'
+ echo ' This is Green'
```

Here it's not entering the `else` part and continuously displaying `This is Green`.

Comment: So what is your input exactly?

Answer (score 0):

It was a small syntax mistake:

```
if [ "$col2" == Success ]
```

This resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is the way that you compare the variable with the string. Use this

```
"$col2" = "Success"
```

Instead of

```
$col2 == 'Success'
```